# Store Production formula in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to develop an web application using Php/MySQL. So I need to store formula of a product in the database such that when the production of a product is finished the raw materials involved during the production can be deducted. I need to retrive the formula such that I can use it in my code to process. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. Can you give an example with actual numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a trigger that is activated before update. Depending on the formulas, you might need to implement a parser in the trigger to apply the formula for each product case.